# best practice for breaking references in C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I was wondering how can I break a reference to an instance if I can't put anything to null (because the program won't work), then can't use Dispose: `(if object!=null) {object.Dispose();}`, and don't know where and how to reinitialize the object (it should reinit all variables also).

Also, where can I find a .Net Memory Profiler good issue advisor that tells you how to resolve his found issues that might indicate memory leaks?

e.g. : for

```
 Direct EventHandler roots (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Disposed instances (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Pinned instances (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Undisposed instances (remove external references) (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Large instances (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Duplicate instances (Show details) (Ignore...)
 Direct delegate roots (Show details) (Ignore...)
```

and so on

Comment: You could try using a [weak reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).

Comment: have tried that, still doesn't work @Robert Harvey

Comment: Well, you need to be more specific about what it is that you're trying to do.  "Doesn't work" doesn't really tell us anything.  Offhand, I'd say that a better solution is to design your application so that it can garbage collect in a more conventional way.

Comment: If you have a convoluted object graph that doesn't permit lopping chunks off then there is only two practices.  Redesigning it.  Or ignoring it because hardware is way cheaper than your time.  A memory profiler isn't going to help you do that.